# read and check for missing .env variables

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I have a `.env` file with those vars:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://my-enpoint.com/api 
REACT_APP_APP_URL=https://my-app.com
ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
REACT_APP_PUSHER_APP_KEY=d83519e4-6017-41f4-b8b2-6093f6480914
```

...etc

I would like to check if any of the variables are missing and print info about missing value in specified variable.

I've tried to read a variables from file in loop but I cannont access to them in loop. Manually its possible, by getting variable one by one. But I want to do it automatically.
My code:

```bash
VARIABLES=("REACT_APP_URL" "REACT_APP_API_URL" "ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS" "REACT_APP_PUSHER_APP_KEY")
source .env
for i in "${!VARIABLES[@]}"; do
  env -S "$(cat .env)" sh -c 'echo '${VARIABLES[$i]}"'
done
```

I have zero exp in bash but I need to make some basic automation in my project

Comment: Since you say that you've got zero experience in Bash, where is the Bash code from? It does some rather weird things.

Comment: Do you need to `source` the `.env` file or just check that the required variables are all defined (and non-empty) in it?

Comment: A minor point: `a=b` does not create an environment variable.  `A=b` also does not create environment variables.  These are all shell variables, but they are not in the environment. (Unless they were already in the environment and you are merely assigning a different value.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell The `.env` file is not supposed to be sourced, it usually gets passed to commands such as `docker run --env-file` to define environment variables via simple assignment for that specific command.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've tried to learn bash by other solutions similar to my expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you’ve posted goes in the right direction but it does many incorrect things and hence doesn’t work:

1. You don’t need to (and should not) `source` the environment file.
2. Your code is iterating over the *indices* of the array `VARIABLES`; why not iterate directly over the values? This simplifies the code.
3. The `-S` flag of `env` doesn’t fulfil a purpose here.
4. Single-quoting the command that we pass to `env` prevents parameter expansion. This means that the command doesn’t actually see the current variable.
5. Passing the contents of the file as command line arguments to `env` unfortunately won’t work — it will just concatenate all variables into a single line. You can avoid this by not quote the substitution, but then it won’t work if any of the values in the `.env` file contains spaces, which is unacceptable.

The last point can probably be solved by some clever trickery involving `xargs` but the resulting code is non-portable. It’s much easier to simply `source` the file *inside* the command that’s executed by `env`.

Lastly, why are we using `env` at all here? Why not just run `sh -c` directly? — Because we want to only look at variables that are defined *inside `.env`*. But the code currently doesn’t do that! To do this, we need to pass `-i` (or `--ignore-environment`) to `env` — in other words: ignore the current environment.

Putting all this together:

```
variables=(REACT_APP_URL REACT_APP_API_URL ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS REACT_APP_PUSHER_APP_KEY)

for var in "${variables[@]}"; do
  env -i sh -c "source ./.env; echo \"\$$var\""
done
```

Some comments:

1. By convention, `ALL_CAPS` is reserved for environment variables. We use `lowercase` for our non-environment variables.
2. You don’t need to quote string literals without special characters (i.e. the values of the `variables` array).
3. We need to pass a path name (`./.env`) to `source`; only using a filename (`.env`) does not work, since `source` then searches the (unset) `$PATH` locations.
4. Don’t forget to quote *all* expansions! This includes quoting *inside* the `sh -c` command, hence `\"\$$var\"`: the backslashes allow nesting the quotation marks (and escape the initial `$` so that the command sees an environment variable name).

This code prints all variables defined in `.env`. If you want to instead *test* whether they’re set, use the following:

```bash
for var in "${variables[@]}"; do
  env -i sh -c "source ./.env; test -v $var || echo \"$var is unset!\""
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
a=1
b=
c=3

vars=(a b c)

for var in ${vars[@]}; {
    [[ ${!var} ]] || echo $var is empty
}
```

Or use grep to check your file:

```
$ cat env
a=1
b=
c=3

$ vars=$(grep -Ev '(a|b|c)=.+' env)
$ [[ $vars ]] && echo $vars not set
b= not set
```

To autocheck all vars in env file:

```
grep -Ev '.+=.+' env
b=
```